# asp.net RangeBar Chart Lable Position

Tags: asp.net

RangeBar Chart

[image: RangeBar Chart]

I want to change the position of label names on the top of Bar.
I tried everything, but label name only changes its position inside the Bar.

Comment: I have working on this problem. But no solution came out.